# Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I fetch API data by axios. Everything is working correct. I try to convert js to tsx. The code for fetching data is briefly as below:

```
let list = null;
...
list = response.data
...
console.log(list.list[2])  //here the problem, first "list" item is red underlined, telling that (Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) )
```

The actual result of `list` is as follows:

```
{
"city":{...}
"cod":"200"
"message":6.1851422
"cnt":10
"list":[...]
}
```

I need the array of list.list. The app is working correctly, but I want to get rid of this warning. I am new to typescript, should I define a type for `list`? Or is there any other way to handle this warning?

Comment: Create Minimal reproductive example. Without your code, we cannot tell you what you are doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would add a type definition for List, that is generally pretty helpful anyways. Also you can add a check to make sure the list exists before trying properties on it. Lastly if you just want to force it to work and say hey typescript I am smarter than you I know this works you can do list!.list[2]. The exclamation point is a non-null-assertion.

Comment: Hi @decpk . The subject is not about the code (it is long and working code), the subject is about converting js to ts, I think the solution is very simple but my knowledge is very limited about typescript

Comment: @ColinHale I tried with "?" and with "!". When I add "!", like this list!.list[2], then the second "list" item on list.list is red underlined, saying that --> Property 'list' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

Comment: Is this a good approach? I replaced let list = null; with let list: List;     

With this approach, there is no error: 
type List = {
    list: string
  }
  let list: List;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to define an interface for list then passing the type when you initialize list. Then do a check to make sure that list exists.

```
type Codes = "200" | "400" | "500"

type City = {
  city: string;
  address: string;
  state: string;
}

interface ListResponse {
  "city": City;
  "cod": Codes
  "message": number;
  "cnt": number;
  "list":string[]
 }

let list: ListResponse | null = null
...
list = response.data
...
if(list){
    console.log(list.list[2])
}
```

Comment: Right, this answer works, I will choose your answer. Can you also briefly tell why aren't we using "type" but using "interface" ?

Comment: Type is a little more flexible than type as you can interface it with other types, and as a general rule you use types for primitive types and interface for more complex things. Ill update the answer to show you a little what i mean.

Comment: Thanks Colin, yes now it is more clear. Thank you, Best Regards..

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `?` operator (more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining))

So, your code would look like:

```
list?.list
```

This short-circuits the expression as `undefined` if it's a `nullish` object!

Also, you can just wrap your statement around an `if` block where you check if the list object is null or not!

**NOTE:** Additionally, you'd need to check the nature of your `list.list` variable before accessing it as an array!

Hope it helps!

Comment: When I add "?", then the second "list" item of list.list[2] is red underlined, again the same warning. And a second "?" cannot be added like this: list?.list?[2]

Comment: Because the first reference to the variable `list` can possibly be null, we need to safe check the object before accessing any value inside it, similarly, nesting down to the second `list`, you still need to check if the value in this variable exists, then only you'll be able to access the `2` index

can also do something like: `list && list.list && list.list[2]`